# Combining the output of multicore results in R

Tags: r, foreach

I am replacing a loop with a `foreach` loop in R. In short foreach package in R uses multiple cores to do the loop and  results are stored in a list.

I have a function that output are `out1,out2,ou3,...,outp`. outputs can vary between digits and letters. Assume we have 3 outputs saying out1=Vector ,out2= Matrix and out3=characters.

What I need is to append all output in all loops. For example

```
first loop
out1 out2   ou3
1    1 1    H
     0 2

second loop
out1 out2   ou3
2    0 1    K
     0 0
```

I need:

```
out1 out2   ou3
1    1 1    H
2    0 2    K
     0 1    
     0 0
```

I see that there is a `.combine` option in `foreach` function but I cannot make that work, for example if I use `rbind` it gives me some strange outputs.

An example of output without merging is provided below. What I am looking for is to append all elements of the same name in list.

```
output of foreach function without merging
List of 2
         $ :List of 31 <<<<<<<<----- this is the first iteration
          ..$ chain          : num [1:37501, 1:11] -0.661 -0.661 -0.661 -0.661 -0.661 ...
          ..$ formula        :Class 'formula' length 3 y ~ .
          .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
          ..$ acceptance.rate: num [1:11] 26 26 26 26 26 ...
          ..$ data           :'data.frame': 50 obs. of  5 variables:
          .. ..$ y : num [1:50] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
          .. ..$ X1: num [1:50] -0.471 -0.522 -1.055 -1.496 -0.833 ...
          .. ..$ X2: num [1:50] -0.876 1.623 -1.223 1.267 -0.978 ...
          .. ..$ X3: num [1:50] 0.674 1.302 1.589 1.398 -0.269 ...
          .. ..$ X4: num [1:50] 0.6942 0.0282 0.5077 -0.5772 -0.8983 ...
          ..$ iterations     : num 50000
          ..$ q.par          : num [1:2] 0 1
          ..$ b.par          : num [1:2] 0 1
          ..$ initials       : num [1:11] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ...
          ..$ burn.in        : num 0.25
          ..$ dist.q         :function (x, m = 0, s = 1, log = FALSE, normalized = TRUE)  
          ..$ dist.b         :function (x, m = 0, s = 1, log = FALSE, normalized = TRUE)  
          ..$ para.b         : num 1
          ..$ para.q         : num 1
          ..$ dist.l         :function (x, min = 0, max = 1, log = FALSE)  
          ..$ l.par          : num [1:2] 0 1000
          ..$ fixed.l        : num 2.17
          ..$ v.scale        : num 0.452
          ..$ sampling       : chr "bin"
          ..$ RejAccChain    : num [1:50001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
          ..$ cov.m          : num 2
          ..$ error          : num 0
          ..$ x              : num [1:50, 1:5] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
          .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
          .. .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
          .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "(Intercept)" "X1" "X2" "X3" ...
          .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:5] 0 1 2 3 4
          ..$ y              : Named num [1:50] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
       ...
         $ :List of 31 <<<<<<<<----- this is the second iteration
          ..$ chain          : num [1:37501, 1:11] -0.158 -0.158 -0.158 -0.158 -0.154 ...
          ..$ formula        :Class 'formula' length 3 y ~ .
          .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
          ..$ acceptance.rate: num [1:11] 25.9 25.9 25.9 25.9 25.9 ...
          ..$ data           :'data.frame': 50 obs. of  5 variables:
          .. ..$ y : num [1:50] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
          .. ..$ X1: num [1:50] -0.471 -0.522 -1.055 -1.496 -0.833 ...
          .. ..$ X2: num [1:50] -0.876 1.623 -1.223 1.267 -0.978 ...
          .. ..$ X3: num [1:50] 0.674 1.302 1.589 1.398 -0.269 ...
          .. ..$ X4: num [1:50] 0.6942 0.0282 0.5077 -0.5772 -0.8983 ...
          ..$ iterations     : num 50000
          ..$ q.par          : num [1:2] 0 1
          ..$ b.par          : num [1:2] 0 1
          ..$ initials       : num [1:11] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 ...
          ..$ burn.in        : num 0.25
          ..$ dist.q         :function (x, m = 0, s = 1, log = FALSE, normalized = TRUE)  
          ..$ dist.b         :function (x, m = 0, s = 1, log = FALSE, normalized = TRUE)  
          ..$ para.b         : num 1
          ..$ para.q         : num 1
          ..$ dist.l         :function (x, min = 0, max = 1, log = FALSE)  
          ..$ l.par          : num [1:2] 0 1000
          ..$ fixed.l        : num 2.17
          ..$ v.scale        : num 0.452
          ..$ sampling       : chr "bin"
          ..$ RejAccChain    : num [1:50001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
          ..$ cov.m          : num 2
          ..$ error          : num 0
          ..$ x              : num [1:50, 1:5] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
          .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
          .. .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
          .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "(Intercept)" "X1" "X2" "X3" ...
          .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:5] 0 1 2 3 4
          ..$ y              : Named num [1:50] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example you can show? If you save all your stuff into a list, you can then do something like rbindlist.

Comment: When I use rbindlist it gives me an error: error calling combine function:
<simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2): use.names should be TRUE or FALSE>

Comment: You need to provide then a working example and code so someone can try running it.